# Very confused with a DAC's SPI protocol

Tags: spi, datasheet

[This](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1792.pdf?ts=1647554070033&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) DAC is controlled by SPI interface. And requires two bytes to write data to one of its registers. Below showing that the first byte is "register index" and the second byte is the data. Which means to me that the first byte is one of the DAC's register which performs a specific action, and the second one is the data to be written to that register.

[image]

And down in the manual there is also the following register map:

[image]

I guess from B15 to B8 selects the register index(first byte) and from B7 to B0 represents the register data(second byte).

Now my problem is I'm totally lost after that point. I cannot figure out what register does what and what the data B7:B0 represents in the datasheet. ATLD, ATR ect what they all together mean is not obvious to me.

To understand this, I decided to ask just one precise question which I hope would help me to understand how things make sense:

How can I set the DAC output to 0.5V? (how is register_index and register_data formed and what that particular register_index mean)

(I hope if someone explain just that, I might understand what things mean)

Comment: It seems the SPI interface is for changing the settings. Looking at Fig. 35, LRCK/DATA/BCK/SCK are used for the audio samples

Comment: This doesnt answer your question, but this might be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNcaNYOuZBE

Comment: I just watched it and he doesn't also explain a word about what those registers "mean/control". He only says there is a mute bit of register 18 and turns it on and off. He doesn't even explain what that register does as a whole. Telling only one bit of it mutes ect. Good for learning SPI but does not answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: Found a project which uses this chip.
https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece477/Archive/2010/Spring/S10-Grp06/hw/Final_Report_Team6.pdf
https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece477/Archive/2010/Spring/S10-Grp06/code-doc/html/files.html
You can find the driver code in "SHARC/PCM1792_SPI.c" and it's usage in "SHARC/main.c". Seems you dont actually need much configuring from the SPI side, just pipe I2S data in

Comment: the register configuration you're interested in is lines 31 to 38 of https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece477/Archive/2010/Spring/S10-Grp06/code-doc/html/_p_c_m1792___s_p_i_8c_source.html

Comment: You can ignore the entire SPI interface. All the registers SPI controls have a default value that is in all likelihood what you want. In particular, the ATL and ATR are attenuation values for Left and Right (with ATLD being a write enable) and they default to 0xff, no attenuation.

Comment: I cannot interpret those resgister meanings. For instance what is the function of register19 or 18 ect. Can anybody describe a few of them from those weird codes?

Answer (score 2):

The registers are explained in the datasheet, in the section "Register Definitions", starting right below the table 4 you posted on page 27.

But you can't set the DAC output value via the control port, as this is an audio DAC, it will output audio that is fed to the audio port. The registers are the control port to configure it and for example set audio output volume.

Comment: You didn’t understand what Im asking about. I know where that section is. But I cannot interpret those resgister meanings from those symbols. For instance what is the function of register19 or 18 ect.

Comment: For the rest thanks for the input about we cannot set the DAC output.

Comment: Well the datasheet explains each bit thoroughly, and it takes about a page per register to explain it, so expanding what those two registers are for won't fit here. For example register 18 is used to set the audio bus format and register 19 is used to select volume ramp speed and set other settings.

Answer (score 2):

The PCM1792 datasheet you point to is actually excellent and highly detailed, but for someone not familiar with reading such datasheets they can be fairly daunting so I’ll try to provide a little primer to hopefully help you over the hump.

First, let’s step back and remember what the basic function of a DAC is: it is to convert digital data at some sample rate, either coming from a parallel interface or in this case a serial interface, to an analog voltage.

The digital data arriving at this chip is sampled audio data presented serially in the industry standard “i2s” format. The “2” in “i2s” denotes two channels, stereo, left and right.

There are only 3 input pins needed for i2s: the left audio channel data (DATA) arrives on 32 consecutive bits, ms bit first, then the right audio comes in on the next 32 bits. The bit clock (BCK) is the signal that strobes these 64 bits, data changing on its falling edge, stable data bit strobed into DAC on rising edge (datasheet, figure 27). The left/right (LRCK) signal is low during the left audio’s 32 bits, high during right. For a 24 bit DAC like this only the first 24 bits contain data, the last 8 bits are padded with zero.

At 48kHz sample rate, the sample period is 1/48000 = 20.6us, which is the period of LRCK.
There are 64 bit clocks per period so it’s frequency is 48K * 64 = 3.07MHz.
The DAC also requires a “system clock” (SCK) at a high multiple of the sample rate, typically 512x (24.6MHz) but this isn’t strictly part of the i2s interface.

So every 20.6us a new pair of analog outputs will be generated based on the left and right digital words strobed in and will get updated to a new value 20.6us later. A low pass filter after the DAC will smooth out the transitions.

Most DACs present a voltage output whose range is specified in the data sheet. But some high end DACs (like this one – the PCM1792 is an elite, ultra high end audio DAC) have current outputs and require and external opamp to convert to a voltage so the voltage levels will be dictated by the external circuitry.

I don’t know what board you’re using, but let’s assume you have a board that converts the DAC output current to a maximum of +5.0V for a full scale positive digital input (0x7fffff) and to -5.0V for a full scale negative input (0x800001). As for your original question, “how do I set the DAC output to 0.5V?”, well, 0.5V would be 10% of full scale so you’d need to apply a digital input of 10% of full scale which is 0x0ccccc. Apply that value (repeatedly, on every sample) to get a DC output of 0.5V.

For some simple DACs that’s all you get – i2s input pins and analog outputs, no fuss, no muss. But fancy parts, like this one, will often offer optional control of advanced settings, and that’s what the SPI interface is for here. I’ll reiterate that you almost certainly don’t need to muck with any of this but for educational purposes I’ll continue.

What are some of these optional features you might want access to? While i2s is an industry standard interface, there are some silly options that hardly anybody uses but the DAC vendor is obliged to support. These are called “PCM audio data formats” and there are 8 options, selectable by the three FMT[2:0] bits in register 18. The table on page 28 shows that the default for these bits is “101” = 24-bit i2s format, which is what you want so don’t change those bits. You’d make sure the data you’re feeding the DAC is in this format.

While we’re looking at register 18, what are these other bits? DMF[1:0] select “Analog-FIR performance”. This is the FIR (finite impulse response) digital filter that is applied internally to the data and affects subtle aspects of the rolloff and ripple near the Nyquist. It defaults to “00” and you should just leave it there.

What about the DME bit? Digital de-emphasis. This would be used if you added high frequency emphasis to the incoming digital signal and you want the DAC to remove it. But you didn’t, so don’t change the default, which is 0, disabled.

What about the MUTE bit, which is bit 0 of register 18? If you wanted to mute the audio you should just apply zeroes in your i2s stream, but for sake of argument let’s say you want to use this MUTE bit to mute the audio at the DAC, how would you do it? You would need to use the SPI interface to write a ‘1’ to bit 0 of register 18 (and then later write it back to ‘0’ to unmute it).

The numbers 16-23 in the Register 16-23 parlance refer to the address presented in bits [14:8]. For some reason Burr Brown only implemented 16-23: addresses 0-15 and 24-127 are undefined.

[image]

We want to write a ‘1’ to the MUTE bit, B0 in Register 18. To do that we would write a single 16-bit word to the DAC via SPI: set bit  B15 = 0 to denote we’re writing, set bits B14:B8 to 18 (0010010), and set bit 0 to 1. That would be a value of 0001001000000001 = 0x1201. That would set the MUTE bit to ‘1 and we’d have muted audio. Unfortunately, we also just wrote zeroes to the other 7 bits (B7:B1) in that register so just screwed up those settings!

There are two ways to properly set just bit B0 and not affect the other bits:

-your software could have a local copy of the Register 18 contents, you’d edit just bit 0 in your code and write back the new value.

-you can first read back the value of Register 18 from the DAC itself, change just bit 0 in your software, then write back new value. This is a more robust method.

The logistics of reading and writing registers depends on whether you’ve configured the DAC to use SPI or I2C mode so I won’t try to go into more detail there.

In registers 16 and 17 there are 8 bit attenuation values of left and right audio: the DAC is capable of applying gain scaling via these registers. But it is more common to just apply the gain scaling you need to the digital data you’re generating in the first place, so you’d leave these registers alone in the default 0xff = no attenuation state.

As for the other registers bits, some as unused (RSVD = reserved), some are read-only (registers 22, 23) for zero-crossing detection and such, and other bits are well described in the datasheet.

The important thing to remember is that if you edit any of these bits make sure you first read back the register so you can restore the bits you don’t want to change to their current value. SPI (or I2C if you want to use that mode) are fussy, hard to debug interfaces that will cause you lots of headaches so have a bottle of aspirin nearby or do what I do – avoid using them.